# How to sync music and pictures with Nokia N9?

Tags: sync, nokia

I bought a **Nokia N9**, and want to **sync my music and pictures** to the device.

> Which software has the ability to do this?

I know there is a way through dual boot or VirtualBox, but i'm interested in software for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Ubuntu 12.04, Rhythmbox can sync music by default. All you have to do is connect the phone to your computer and open Rhythmbox. It should detect it by default and all you have to do is right click on your device and click sync. :)